# WPF TextBlock custom wrapping : on the left and after a "."

Tags: wpf, trim, textblock, word-wrap

I'm trying to display a text that would be wrapped on the left and only after special characters in the string.

I Hope the first part could be done in XAML, and I'm pretty sure the second part cannot.

The aim is to wrap a text this way :
- Original text : "Object1.Object2.Object3.Property1"
- Wrapped text could be (depending on the width available for the text):
- - "....Object2.Object3.Property1"
- - "....Object3.Property1"
- - "....Property1"

Do you know anyway to do that? I tried to use the TextBlock "TextWrapping" and "TextTrimming" properties, without success.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with TextWrapping nor another WPF property. Instead you can write a custom [converter](http://www.dev102.com/2008/07/17/wpf-binding-converter-best-practices/) and send the width of textblock as a [binding parameter](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/88a22766-5e6f-4a16-98a6-1ab39877dd09).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the binding parameters also helped me with another topic :-)
I'll try to write the converter, but it's an overhead to use everytime that I don't like so much. I'll see.